# Как хранятся данные о товарах в интернет-магазина

Tags: база-данных, интернет-магазин

Возможно глупый вопрос, но недавно столкнулся с таким понятием, как '**фид**'. Как я понял, именно эти **фиды** и используются интернет-магазинами для отображения товара. Но я не понимаю одной вещи. Зачем нужны **фиды**, если есть база данных?

Comment: Где столкнулись?

Comment: @andreymal на работе(

Comment: Вероятно, на работе и стоит спросить, что там имеют в виду под понятием «фид» в данном контексте

Comment: @andreymal контекст вполне понятен. Это XML файл с описанием товаров, но зачем он нужен, когда есть база данных, я не знаю

Comment: И я подозреваю, что на самом деле всё наоборот — из базы данных генерируется XML-файл для каких-то нужд

Comment: @andreymal окей, тогда уточню. Думал, что это более распространённое понятие. Но возможно кто-нибудь знает ответ

Comment: @andreymal тоже так думал, но моя задача - вручную отредактировать файлик фида. Если бы он из базы генерировался, то странно было бы это всё в файле менять

Comment: Возможно, фид нужен для какого-нибудь [Google Merchant Center](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7439882). Но если бы мне поставили задачу интегрироваться с ним, я бы сгенерировал XML-файл из базы

Comment: @andreymal кстати, вполне возможно. Но зачем мне тогда файл руками редактировать. Как много вопросов и так мало ответов...

Comment: почему вручную лучше спросить у владельца или  того, кто ставил задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фиды  нужны для экспорта в стороние сервисы, вроде google, facebook ремаркетинг, у mail.ru тоже  что то подобное  есть.

Эти сервисы понятия  не имеют о товарах вашего магазина и о вашей бд и ее структуре,  и парсерить сайт ради  товаров , которые вы  хотите рекламировать, не будут.

Поэтому на сайтах  генерируют фиды  -  xml или иных форматов файлы,  чтобы быстро получить  информацию о товарах, которые должны участвовать в рекламной кампании.

Там передается вся необходимая инфомрмация -  названия, картинка, есть  ли доставка, стоимость,  скидка и тд.

Ну а потом, на основе этих данных, на различных сайтах вам  показывают товары, которые вы просматривали на другом сайте )...

Надеюсь смог  объяснить)